# javascript как вызвать функцию название которой содержится в массиве

Tags: javascript

У меня есть много команд, на каждую из которых надо вызывать определенную функцию, я хочу содержать их названия в массиве.

```js
const Commands_Array = [['Создать сет','set_function'],['Баланс','Balance_function']];
function Command_processing(command){
    alert(command);
    for (let i = 0; i < Commands_Array.length; i++){
        if (Commands_Array[i][0] == command){
            Commands_Array[i][1]();
        }
    }
}
```

Если я вызову функцию: `Command_processing("Создать сет");`

Соответственно в данном случае я хочу вызвать функцию: "set_function", как мне это записать по синтаксису? `Commands_Array[i][1]();`

Comment: ну да, ток функции объявите

Comment: @ThisMan то есть? Я нуб в js(

Comment: Commands_Array  как я понимаю хранит название функций, но не вызывает. Допустим в нем хранится функция getStatus;  Пример:  Commands_Array = [getStatus] Тогда вы можете обратится к массиву  Commands_Array[индекс в нашем случае 0] достанет переменную, но мы так и не вызываем ее, что бы вызывать, нужно использовать ()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Удобнее всего в этом случае хранить ваши функции в объекте, а не в массиве. И можно сразу объявить их там, чтобы не добавлять избыточный шаг поиска по имени функции. Два варианта:

```js
const Commands_Object = {
  'Создать сет': function() { alert('set_function'); },
  'Баланс': function() { alert('Balance_function'); },
};

function Command_processing(command, commands) {
    alert(command);
    
    if (commands[command]) commands[command]();
    else alert(`'${command}' not found.`);
}

Command_processing('Создать сет', Commands_Object);
Command_processing('Фу Бар', Commands_Object);
```

```js
function set_function() { alert('set_function'); }
function Balance_function() { alert('Balance_function'); }

const Commands_Object = {
  'Создать сет': set_function,
  'Баланс': Balance_function,
};

function Command_processing(command) {
    alert(command);
    
    if (Commands_Object[command]) Commands_Object[command]();
    else alert(`'${command}' not found.`);
}

Command_processing('Создать сет');
Command_processing('Фу Бар');
```

Comment: Отлично, но вы храните функции прямо в объекте эти функции будут большими их просто не удобно будет читать

Comment: @artemgh Если функции большие, их можно объявить отдельно, а в объект добавить ссылки на них (то есть просто имена функций).

Comment: @artemgh Добавил второй вариант.

Comment: Отлично, как я понимаю в данном случае, мне даже не нужен цикл?

Comment: @artemgh Да, при таком хранении не нужно обходить весь массив циклом каждый раз, функция находится за один шаг.

Comment: а можете подсказать как сделать так , чтобы и объект с которым сравниваем, тоже передавался функции как параметр?

Comment: @artemgh Отредактировал первый пример.